# How are reference letters for postdocs submitted?

Tags: etiquette, job-search, postdocs, recommendation-letter

I am right now beginning my first application for my first post-doctoral position. The announcement lists a series of documents which should be submitted, including (quite predictably) a reference letter from my supervisor.

How would such letter normally be delivered? I am asking because of a certain cognitive dissonance. On one hand, the application lists it just like another document, which would suggest that I should simply get it from my supervisor and send it together with all the remaining paperwork. On the other hand, I remember that when I was applying for my PhD, the process of submitting references was rather more complicated, and specifically excluded me having access any of the reference letters. So maybe I should ask him to post his opinion directly to where I'm applying. How do these things typically work? (I imagine that if no clarification is given, there is a universally agreed way...)

If it matters, I’m now in UK, and applying for a position in Eastern Europe. I study pure mathematics.

Comment: What field are you in? The answer in mathematics is quite different (and more civilized) than in other fields, for example.

Comment: @TomChurch: I'm in mathematics

Comment: generally it varies case-by-case; what is certain is that they will not be directly provided by you. The place you're applying for either uses some automated system where you send your referee a link for them to upload the letters, or your perspective PI asks you for the letter in person, and you tell your referee to send the letter to him/her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postdocs in mathematics in the US are universally* handled through [MathJobs](https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs), which was commissioned by the American Mathematical Society for this purpose. Recommenders submit a single letter, which can then be attached by the applicant to any number of applications, without ever giving the applicant access to the letter. Recommenders can also send a more specific letter to particular schools if desired.

This system has been so successful that it has been made available to other fields as [AcademicJobsOnline](https://academicjobsonline.org/ajo) by the Duke University Mathematics Department, who originally created MathJobs.

I do not know whether positions in Eastern Europe use MathJobs, however.

*If anyone knows of a postdoc in math in the US that does not use MathJobs, I'd be interested to know; it's been a few years since I last heard of one.